# How do i have a single Chart.vue component instead of different chart components and then display charts from it by changing id of the API

Tags: vue.js, components, chart.js

I am displaying four charts, so i have created four different chart components, but all the components are same but they differ in API id.

In order to make code effective, i want to make a single Chart.vue component and then display the chart in any other component by their respective ID.

Here is one of my chart component:

```
 <template>
      <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height: 25vh; width:100%;">
        <canvas id="DisplayChart" ></canvas>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import moment from 'moment'
    export default {
      name: 'Chart',
      async mounted () {
        await this.$http.get('/farfrom/chart/3') //Here 3 is the ID of the chart.
          .then((response) => {
            const result = response.data
            const ctx = document.getElementById('DisplayChart').getContext('2d')
            const Chart_data = []
            for (let i = 0; i < result.date.length; i++) {
              Chart_data.push({
                x_axis: moment(result.date[i], 'X').toDate(),
                y_axis: result.challenge[i]
              })
            }
            let myChart
            if (myChart !== undefined) {
              myChart.destroy()
            }
            myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'Chart_from_API',
                    data: Chart_data,
                ]
              },
              options: {
                lineTension: 0,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: false
                      },
                      ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                        callback (value) {
                          return `${value  }k`    // y-axis value will append k to it
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  xAxes: [
                    {
                      type: 'time',
                      time: {
                        unit: 'month'
                      },
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

i have imported this in another component like:

```
    <template>
      <div class="chart-container">
        <Chart></Chart>
      </div>
    </template>
  
    <script>
    import Chart from 'Chart.vue'
    ....
    </script>
```

Here i have shown the example of one of my chart among 4 charts, my other charts are also same only change is in the id of the API.

Now as i said i want to know how i can make one Single Chart.vue with some variable to API Id and use it in any component by their respective id. Please do help me in this.

Objective: I want to have a single Chart.vue component instead of 4 charts, and if i want to use any chart i should be able to use their respective id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **props** to pass data to a child component.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

#### Example

*App.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Chart :id="chartId" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from "@/components/Chart.vue";
// @/ means src/

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Chart,
  },
  data: () => ({
    chartId: 2,
  }),
};
</script>
```

*Chart.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ id }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Chart",
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const apiURL = `/farfrom/chart/${this.id}`;
    // API call
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i did exactly the way you said but i am getting "chartId" string as the output instead of line chart.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put `:` to bind data before `id` in <Chart :id="chartId" />

Comment: With `<Chart id="chartId" />` you pass an string "chartId".
With `<Chart :id="chartId" />` you pass the value of variable `chartId` (the value is 2 in the example).

Comment: Using `:id="chartId"` is equivalent to use `v-bind:id="chartId"`.

Comment: Yeah, i did the same thing, but it is just showing me '2', rather i wanted the chart figure of id=2

Comment: Use `this.id` variable to make the API call to the receive the data of the id that you pass as prop.

Comment: `{{ id }}` is just an example, complement with your code, like `<canvas ...> ... </canvas>`

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can display chart. I have used <canvas id="DisplayChart" ></canvas> in Chart component only as u can see in my question. My objective is to display chart by their respective id(id means in api). Earlier i had used different chart components in order to display the chart, and i had imported everything to App.vue, but now i want to do it effectively by only one chart component.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question. You could use a library to display the chart, like Vuetify (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sparklines/) or https://vue-chartjs.org/.

Comment: I am actually looking to display charts, i have different chart components and i have imported it separately and displayed it in App.vue. All charts are same but they differ only in API id, so now i want have only one Chart component and when i want to display it i should be able to display it by their API id respectively.